# Omni auth Configuring Force login for Twitter (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth gem for Twitter authentication,
i am trying to configure `force_login = true` in omniauth,
so that each time user tries to add a twitter account, he will be prompted to login.

right now if a user is already logged in, his account is shown.

I tested and found if i can pass "force_login=true" in the url, i could get this done.
But not sure how i can achieve this with configuring omniauth.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding `authorize_params: {force_login: 'true'}` along with the provider configuration in `/config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file.